# VLC stream on Raspberry Pi

Tags: stream, raspberry-pi, vlc

I want to stream Raspberry Pi camera to network.

I streamed video with this command line very well on vlc version 2.0.3 (Twoflower)

`cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:width=640:height=480:fps=10 --v4l2-vflip 1 --v4l2-hflip 1 --sout "#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090}"`

After update the vlc to 2.2.1 (Terry Pratchett), I can not open stream. Raspicam led start to light, everything seems ok but i can not open stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. I think vlc version (2.2.1) or v4l does not support direct streaming. So I have to transcode my stream. My new streaming command line is

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:width=640:height=480:fps=15 --v4l2-vflip 1 --v4l2-hflip 1 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=mp4v}:std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090}"
```

Now it works well.